# Kendo Grid not waiting for toolbar drop down lists to finish before loading

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So I have a Kendo grid, that has two DropDownLists (DDL) in the toolbar.

The issue I am having is, the grid is dependent on the two DDLs, one which is loaded via an ajax call.  However the grid does its ajax call before the DDL is populated, which leads to a failed call.

How can I force the grid to wait for the DDL to be populated.

Note: I CAN NOT give it a default value.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [`autoBind`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-autoBind) to `false`. This will create the Grid but not load the data.

Then in the `DropDownList` [`dataBound`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#events-dataBound) event force the Grid to be loaded by invoking [`grid.dataSource.read`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-read).

Comment: Didn't think of that, its actually so obvious.  Much appreciated.